# Xcode stuck on Generating Previews when Migrating to Swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

Xcode is stuck Generating Previews after trying to migrate my project from `Swift 2.3` to `Swift 3`.

Is there anyway to check the status of this process without cancelling?

I'm using Cocoapods and I've already changed all of the Swift pods to `Swift 3` versions.

[image: Generating preview]

Comment: It really takes time. In my case, it succeeded after hours.

Comment: I spend on it more than 8 hours, and still stuck on "Generating preview..." next morning.

Comment: I downloaded Xcdoe again and worked after about an hour

Answer (score 3):

For people that are still stuck at "Generating Preview". Check if you have any class names defined that clashes with the (new) public api in Swift 3.

E.g. I had an 'Error.swift' class, which I had to rename. Since all 'NS' prefixes are being removed, this would cause the converter to keep running without providing us an error message.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem, but the origin of the problem was not in my code, but in **Alamofire** framework, in version below 4 they had **Error.swift** class. So I had to update versions of dependencies through **cocoapods** at first. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this problem with which you can at least complete the process and start working on migration.

1. Select targets to convert as usual
2. Wait until the converter gets stuck
3. Open **Activity Monitor** and kill the **swift** process
4. Now the converter will continue and finish the work.

Answer (score 1):

Running migration from the command line worked for me. Try using this script:

https://gist.github.com/davidahouse/18dd78bef7ae543117c396f8c950ccfe

Comment: How / where do you  execute this script?

Comment: First, make sure Ruby is installed (`brew install ruby`). Then go to your project's folder in Terminal and type `ruby <path to downloaded migrator.rb>`. An easy way to get the path to a file in Terminal is to just drag the file from a Finder window into Terminal, and it will add the path.

Comment: Thanks got it eventually, out of interest why does is the script more effective than converting via editor in Xcode?

Comment: got an error `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "swift-update", not a developer tool or in PATH`